# How to write select Statement based on score column result using SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actually my requirement is somthing like below
I need to get student details with score and result
**Condition:**
if score is more than 70 then result will be pass or else fail
score column can get from DB based on score need to find out result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s.*, case when score is null
                 then '--'
                 when score > 70
                 then 'pass'
                 else 'fail'
            end as result
from students s
```

Comment: If score column is null then how  i should display "--"